# Generated background image with CSS or Canvas

Tags: html, css, canvas, background

Recently found this image:

[image]

Original size of image is more than 2MB.

I want to set to background of my project something like that.

I wonder, if it is possible to generate something like that without any image but with new web technologies like CSS3, HTML5 Canvas... or something like that?

If not, how can I reduce size without touching image width and height? is that possible?

Comment: What format is it in and what size does it have?

Answer (score 1):

It is absolutely possible with canvas.

See: http://js1k.com/2011-dysentery/demo/955

http://js1k.com/2010-first/demo/171

http://js1k.com/2011-dysentery/demo/993

There's also this particle system: http://www.mrspeaker.net/dev/parcycle/

Comment: Examples has nothing to do with my image)))

Comment: Well, I wouldn't say "nothing". They are not your image, that's true, but they should show you how to use canvas and JS to create complex shapes and graphics. It was meant as a starting point.

Answer (score 0):

You could create an SVG or canvas element, fill it with your desired pattern, set its size to `width:100%;height:100%;position:absolute;` and its index to `z-index:-1;` to push it behind your content. You can't create an image with CSS3, as CSS3 will only enables you to insert an url (img or `data://`url) (see http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-background/#backgrounds).

To create an image like this with canvas you should learn about the canvas primitives, you can achieve a very basic result with `fillRect`. Same for SVG, although both are not that well supported in the last generation browser versions. Maybe you wish to create your `img` by the server and use the CSS `background:;` property.

Comment: Seems, it will be impossible from the aspect of backward compatibility. Do you know, good way to radically reduce image size without quality loss?

Comment: If the image is abstract and contains the same pattern over and over, you could try PNG. If it contains a very small amount of different colors (less then 255), use GIF. Otherwise use JPEG with a quality of less than 80%, load an alternative JPEG with 100% *after* your website has loaded completely and replace it.

Comment: Actually, you can create complex beautiful patterns with just CSS: http://lea.verou.me/css3patterns/ 
But they are _patterns_, not just any image.

Answer (score 0):

1) Yes you can draw something similar with Canvas (the matter of finding right procedures) and even apply it as a css background using Canvas.toDataURL()

`background: url(<string_from_toDataURL>)`

2) If this image has a lot of repetitive patterns you can try saving it as 8bit PNG. If you are on windows `irfan view` has a nice ability to decrease color depth.